# Why is there a white line / extra padding at the end of my Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Answer found!! Has been posted below. I had a look in the grid.less file and the grid gutter width was being set in there.

I am building a responsive website in bootstrap, compiling with less and grunt.

I have used the bootstrap div class grid `col-md-4` to make 3 equal sized grid boxes.

I don't want a border and haven't added one, but on the right hand side of my page there is a white gap on the right next to the scroll bar that I cannot get rid of. Also, when I make the window size smaller there is a white gap between the `col-md-12` grid above it. How can I fix this? I have no idea (very new to this) and searching doesn't yield me with any solution so I haven't put an attempt as fixing this as I do not have one. Any suggestions would be fantastic, please.

For the white gap

I have tried adding `width:100%;` to the override.less CSS file.

here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="text-center"><img src="gridimage1SMALL.png"></div>
    <div class="classWithPadTITLES">
        <h2><b>     <center>Title </center>  </b></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="classWithPad">
        <p> content
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 3 of these, for each grid box.

CSS

```
.col-md-4 {
    background-color:#333;  /*replaced old colour rgba(97,7,166,1.00) with grey*/
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:semilight;
    height: 450px;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Might be useful to add a fiddle/pen showcasing the issue.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `<center>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured in the variables.less there is some code setting the grid gutter width:

@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
It was at 30px, if I change this to 0px and move it to my overriding variables.less file, I have no white lines anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

As body has some initial margin and padding. Remove that

```
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I added it with a .body but no different. the footer and jumbotron image is fine...

Comment: body is not a class its a tag. use body (without dot) not .body.